# I get the error "ImportError: libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" while deploying my python app to Zyte

Tags: python, tkinter, scrapy, web-crawler, zyte

I searched this question on internet and the most of the solutions suggest me to install tkinter. Tkinter has been installed but the error still persists. Please someone guide me on this[image]

Comment: Your spider uses `turtle` graphics?

Comment: You can try to install all the necessary libraries in a separate `venv` and then run your script from it.

Comment: @Manualmsdos, this type I ran the shub delpoy command inside a virtual environment but this same error came. Did I get you wrong. can you please elaborate more

Comment: @Rija Shaheed, I just assumed that the cause of the error was the [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)